# Dashed border on link is appearing solid

Tags: css, attributes, border

I want the border attribute on a visited link to render dashed. I can only get it to render solid and I can't figure out why. Any help would be great. Thanks

Here is the css code I'm using:

```
    .entry-content p a{
color: #333;
border-bottom: solid #beff00 3px;
}

.entry-content p a:hover{
color: #333;
border-bottom: solid #78b3e0 3px;
}

.entry-content p a:visited{
color: #333;
border-bottom: #78b3e0 dashed;
}
```

You can view it in action at [this blog post](http://www.seanhubbard.com/blogtest).

Comment: have you tried "3px dashed #78b3e0" ? (mind the order)

Comment: @PoeHaH: That should be the case for all of the border attributes, really. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-bottom

Comment: Believe it or not, order isn't fixing it here. Hmm.

Comment: @VinnyBurgh And it's not only the not-displaying-dashed that's messing up here. When I reordered the bits and removed the unnecessary color attributes, the rules for `:hover` and `:visited` don't work at all (http://jsfiddle.net/VEuFm), and it still doesn't seem to work even when I reduce the components down to their most specific form: http://jsfiddle.net/VEuFm/1/. Quite strange.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like the [border conflict resolution](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution) that happens on tables. Of course, it *shouldn't* be happening because there are no tables to be seen, but the order of precendence of styles ( solid > dashed ) seems to be holding true. Also stumped, just thought I'd throw this out there.

Comment: Hm. It seems the issue occurs with style and width, but not with color.

Comment: Now for something else weird: http://jsfiddle.net/VEuFm/6/ and something even weirder: http://jsfiddle.net/VEuFm/7/

Comment: Anyway, using `bottom-border-style: dashed` with `:hover` works, so I'm not sure what the problem with `:visited` is.

Comment: At first I thought maybe it was a browser caching issue -- it is possible to set your browser to not remember pages you've previously visited, hence you'd never have a "visited" link -- but it's apparently only affecting the border properties on the :visited pseudo selector.

Comment: @JAB indeed the issue is happening with both style and width (not color).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, it's the result of a privacy issue. Refer to the following links:

- [Privacy and the :visited selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector) (MDN)
- [Preventing attacks on a user's history through CSS :visited selectors](http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy)
- [Limitations on Styling Visited Links](http://www.impressivewebs.com/styling-visited-links/)

Per the links above, the styling of `a:visited` links is restricted to the use of color-based properties only.

Comment: +1. You, sir, are a genius. Or, at least, a better Googler than me.

Comment: Hardly, but I won't argue with you either! ;)

Comment: Now that's quite interesting.

Comment: Thank You Vinny. Thank you all. This was my first question posted to StackOF and I'm shocked by the speed and accuracy of the replies. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS rule :

```
.entry-content p a:visited {
    border-bottom: 3px dashed #78B3E0;
 }
```

The border rule order is : `border: <width> <style> <color>;`